# SQl query to get unique records

Tags: sql-server

I have the below data:

```
pdtid  version  col1 col2 col3

1        1       0     0   0
1        2       0     0   0
1        3       0     0   0 
2        1       0     0   0
2        2       1     1   0
3        1       0     0   0
4        1       0     0   0
4        2       0     1   0
```

How do I write a query that returns `pdtid` 1 and 3 when it meets the condition `col1 = 0`, `col2 = 0` and `col3 = 0`?

**Edit**: `pdtid` should only be returned if **all** records with a `pdtid` meet the criterium `col1=0 and col2=0 and col3=0`

In this example, the result should return pdtid 1 and 3, but not 2, because 2 contains a record which does not meet the criteria.

Comment: With a where clause? It is not at all clear what you are trying to do here.

Comment: I need to get pdtid 1,3 where col1,2,3 are 0. ignore pdtid 2 since version 2 for pdtid 2 is 1 for col1

Answer (score 3):

Isn't this as simple as writing a normal `SELECT` statement?

```
SELECT  pdtid
  FROM  table
  WHERE col1 = 0 AND
        col2 = 0 AND
        col3 = 0
```

Or if you just want distinct entries, add the `DISTINCT` clause:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT pdtid
  FROM  table
  WHERE col1 = 0 AND
        col2 = 0 AND
        col3 = 0
```

**EDIT**

Following clarification that you'd like to return the `pdtid` ONLY when `col1`, `col2`, and `col3` are 0 for all `version`s, see below.

Try the following which should show you how to achieve this using a nested table that `SUM`s the values for each of the columns before you `SELECT` from it:

```
CREATE TABLE #table (pdtid INT, [version] INT, col1 INT, col2 INT, col3 INT)
INSERT INTo #table (pdtid, [version], col1, col2, col3) VALUES (1, 1, 0, 0, 0), (1, 2, 0, 0, 0), (1, 3, 0, 0, 0), (2, 1, 0, 0, 0), (2, 2, 1, 1, 0), (3, 1, 0, 0, 0), (4, 1, 0, 0, 0), (4, 2, 0, 1, 0)

SELECT  pdtid
  FROM  (   SELECT  pdtid, SUM(col1) AS col1, SUM(col2) AS col2, SUM(col3) AS col3
              FROM  #table
              GROUP BY pdtid) a
  WHERE a.col1 = 0 AND
        a.col2 = 0 AND
        a.col3 = 0

DROP TABLE #table
```

Comment: ya but this will return pdtid 2 also, since col1=0,col2=0,col3=0 for version 1

Comment: How do you identify that you don't want to return a `pdtid` of 2?

Comment: return pdtid only if all col1,col2,col3 =0 for all versions

Comment: @sandra I've modified my answer to contain a new query that should solve your problem for you.

Comment: col1,2,3 are not integer field  they are char fields has some text values to compare

Comment: Creating temporary tables is far too complicated. This is procedural thinking. In SQL, think more in terms of sets and subsets.

Comment: @Giosco I thought it quite obvious that the temporary tables were there to illustrate the statement I was using to solve the problem with an example, as opposed to being the solution. Thanks for your advice though

Comment: @MartinParkin Yes, I understand. But in SQL, many people tend to think procedural, while in fact you can do it with set-oriented statements. E.g. I like the "RDNR" answer in this thread. I assume it also works with a MINUS operator, I'm still thinking ...

Answer (score 1):

This is a ***Relational Division with no Remainder (RDNR)*** problem. See this [**article**](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/high-performance-relational-division-in-sql-server/) by Dwain Camps that provides many solution to this kind of problem.

```
SELECT t.ptid
FROM Test t
WHERE 
    t.col1 = '0'
    AND t.col2 = '0'
    AND t.col3 = '0'
GROUP BY t.ptid
HAVING 
    COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Test WHERE ptid = t.ptid)
```

Comment: This is a great article, thanks for the link! But I assume this overshoots the mark ;)

Answer (score 0):

Could use a correlated Subquery.

```
 SELECT  pdtid
      FROM table A
      WHERE col1 = 0 and col2=0 and col3 = 0
     and not exists (Select 1 
                     from table B 
                     where A.pdtid=b.pdtid AND 
                           (col1<> 0 or col2 <> 0 or col3 <> 0)
```

Basically this generates a set of data where col1,2,3 are not 0 and says only return records that are 0 and not in the set defined not as 0.

or... as a join

```
SELECT  A.pdtid
FROM foo A
LEFT JOIN (Select pdtid
           from foo B 
           where B.col1+B.col2+B.col3 <> 0)  B
on A.pdtid=B.pdtid
WHERE A.col1+A.col2 +A.col3 = 0
and B.pdtid is null
group by A.pdtid
```

working [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb4f5/7/0)

but if we want to simply use where clause and not sum up values... [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/eb4f5/8/0)

```
SELECT  A.pdtid
FROM foo A
LEFT JOIN (Select pdtid
           from foo B 
           where B.col1<> 0 or B.col2 <> 0 or B.col3 <> 0)  B
on A.pdtid=B.pdtid
WHERE A.col1=0 AND A.col2=0 AND A.col3 = 0
and B.pdtid is null
group by A.pdtid
```

Comment: Attention! Your exception query looks for `col1 <> 0 AND col2 <> 0 AND col3 <> 0` -- you should use OR instead of AND. She also wants to exclude a record e.g. with col1=1 and col2=0!

Comment: obfuscated the where clause a bit but it may be more readable.

Comment: there is no col1=1, col2=2 or col3 = 3.  There are +'s we know that in the case where col1+col2+col3=0 then all values are zero and that's the rows she wants.  and we know where col1+col2+col3 would be ID's she doesn't want.  and by including those from the first set, not in the second set, we should get the desired results.

Comment: I wrote MINUS 3  !!!! Also, you must of course think of a generic case, not just the case she posted here !

Comment: two other working examples.  For some reason the fiddle for the correlated subquery which should be the most efficient isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

A generic solution utilizes GROUP BY/HAVING:

```
select pdtid
from tab
group by pdtid
having max(case when col1 = 0 then 0 else 1 end) = 0 -- returns 1 for any other value
   and max(case when col2 = 0 then 0 else 1 end) = 0
   and max(case when col3 = 0 then 0 else 1 end) = 0
```

or NOT EXISTS:

```
select distinct pdtid
from tab as t1
where not exists
 ( select *
   from tab as t2
   where t1.pdtid = t2.pdtid 
     and (col1 <> 0 or col2 <> 0 or col3 <> 0) -- might not work correctly when NULLs exist
 )
```